# Capture all output to log in CherryPy

Tags: python, logging, cherrypy

My cherrypy application (3.2.2 on Python 2.6) is using 3rd party libs, and these libs use standard logging internally, like so:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.info("a message from some library")
```

Now, in my cherrypy config, I have:

```
log.access_file = '/path/access.log'
log.error_file = '/path/error.log'
```

but only CP messages ever appear in these two files, not any of the other logging. But I need all logging there, not just the logging that CP itself issues internally.

Is there a way to capture *all* output, including the 3rd party logging (which I assume goes into stdout/stderr and then disappears, as the process is a detached daemon), into `/path/error.log`? Plug arbitrary stdout/stderr into CP's log somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?  All output into the error log?

```
python yourCherryServer.py &>> /path/error.log
```